# Google app engine project update

Tags: google-app-engine

I am new to google app engine. I am uploading localhost host project created in python to google app engine. It is uploading successfuly, but js changes are not reflecting live. I have flushed Memcache, but it is not working. How can I get rid of this problem?

Comment: When you uploaded the new version of your application, did you change the `version:` field in your `app.yaml`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a built in cache in google app engine for static file, you can control the duration of the cache by using [default_expiration](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_File_Handlers) (or [setting expiration per folder](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/appconfig#Static_Directory_Handlers)).

You should also add a slug (using md5, random, timestamp, or svn revision) in the resource url to force the client to load the resources e.g. `/script/my_script?ver=XXX`.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried emptying your browsers cache? Could also be some other cache along the way, if you are on a cooperate network,for example.